# Email Workflow for every Friday

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a list in my SharePoint site.I have one column named with Project Manager(People Picker). When i add a record in this list,I want to send an email to specified Project Manager every Friday to review that record.For this I have to create a workflow using SharePoint Designer 2010.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1):

This link shows how to send emails daily. You can easily change it to send weekly reminders. 
[Email Daily Reminders](http://sharepointmagazine.net/articles/the-dog-ate-my-task-use-sharepoint-designer-to-email-daily-task-reminders)

(Sometimes you only just need to tweak your search parameters while googling to hit on the right one!)

Answer (score 0):

can you please check this link. It may be help for you.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32753/Send-scheduled-Reminder-Alerts-by-email-in-SharePo

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i want to do this using SharePoint Workflow.Can you please suggest me . How to do this?